# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'. after adding Parse SDK

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I just downloaded and added the Parse SDK to android studio to use with my app. When I added the two lines Parse told me too, to my build.gradle it gave me this error.

```
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

The two lines I added were:

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'}
```

this is what my build.gradle looks like:

```
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.simple.plain.christmascountdown"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'
}
```

I don't understand why I am getting this error. I have seen that some people change the `1.+` part of the code to the version number but this hasn't worked for me?
If any extra information is needed to be provided let me know. Thanks

[My Libs Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICSPK.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You really don't want to use increment versions with `compile` statements.

For example - if You used ParseQueryAdapter while Parse SDK was 1.9.2 Your app might run in trouble since it removed from the newest one i.e.`compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.10.3'` because it's move to ParseUI which is completely different package.

Additionaly, don't use `*.jar` from Parse if You have one and want to use the newest one. As You probably know - since 1.10 it's moved to GitHub and can be compiled just like the rest of libs. If You use *.jar lib - delete Parse lib from Your project and compile the 1.10.3 version instead.

Comment: Thanks Jean, so what your saying is to remove the '+' from the end of statement and put in 1.10.3??

Comment: Yup, that's what I meant. I even read article about that few days ago - it's just safer to use. Should work for Your problem as well - if not, let me know and will try something else.

Comment: I changed it, but it is still throwing up the same error?

Comment: @DeclanMorgan one more thing: I suspect that You are using Parse SDK *.jar file which can cause error while trying to compile to very similar libs. What libs are You using through `compile file tree` statement? If that would be true, no need for multiDexSupport.

Comment: Jean, when i was on the parse.com website it told me to downoad and unzip the parse SDK, I unzipped it into the libs directory in my project which extracted everything in the file? so I have .jar files as well as .jar.properties files. Also when I added the 'multiDexEnabled' code it threw up this new error 

`Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/parse/AbstractQueryController$1.class`

Comment: Everything clear now. They didn't updated documentation on this one apparently. Delete Parse lib from Your project and compile the 1.10.3 version. No need for multiDexSupport - You just wanted to compile the same lib twice and that's causing the error. Updated my answer as well

Comment: I sort of get where your coming from, however I don't know what you mean by deleteing? i added a ink to a snapshot of my libs directory above!

Comment: Oh gosh, it's cluttered. You're supposed to use just Parse-1.10.3.jar (if You want to use SDK from jar), if anything. Or do like I do - use no jar and just compile it like mentioned before.

Comment: So, You have two options now: delete all the libs from parse and use `compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.10.3'` or delete `compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.10.3'` and use *.jar through `compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')`

Comment: I deleted all the directories from Parse and run the projec, it's working with no errors so thank you!. One question, why did they tell me to extract the SDK if i didn't need it?

Comment: Get used to it - they don't write everything they should in documentation. That's why StackOverflow exists :) You can accept my answer with green tick to the left so others can use it as well :)